# IIS 7.5 Default Web Site Directory deleted accidentally

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I deleted the "Default Web Site" Home directory in my IIS 7.5. So i lost my local host online ASP.NET web applications, when i try to re-publish ,I can't see the "wwwroot" in the "inetpub" directory. What i have to do now ? I have to reinstall the IIS, If so, How i reinstall it ?

Comment: simply want to install IIS or what?

Comment: I would suggest you first try system restore. And then if you want to reinstall IIS here are the steps http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Comment: @ Guru Kara : When I check the system Restore in my Windows 7 system, it show the last date as '06 Sep 2012', I go with it ?

Comment: I did system restore, now my deleted web applications are working fine. I get "Default Web site" home directory and "wwwroot" directory in C:\inetpub. Thanks to Guru

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late answering this question, but I had this happen to me. The solution is to create the empty directories that were deleted. Once you start running Visual Studio, VS will populate all the files within the directories.